# Should function variants be provided for all integer types?

Tags: c, coding-style

I am working with a function in a C library that takes a number as a parameter. Currently that means I have two versions, one for `double` and one for `int`.

What versions of functions should I provide for numeric types?

It is common to see this in the standard libraries, but they are not consistent enough to use a guideline e.g. `atof`, `atol` and `atoi` is one set, and `strtod`, `strtol`, `strtoul` is a different set and `abs`, `labs` is a third. That's three different sets, with different naming schemes all in the same header file.

Edit:

This is not for a single use, and I do not know what variants are needed.

Ideally it would support every single standard variant, so is it sufficient to write three in the style of the `strto*` functions and making the user promote types where needs be?

Comment: unless you have a need, one of pair floating/integer should be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do you have a need for more function variants?**

I suspect that given this question needs to be asked, you only have a requirement for a `double` and an `int`, your two functions. If you have a genuine need to support a `double complex` for instance, build a specialized function to handle that.

Comment: This is for a generic library that will be packaged and kept as a binary for several different projects. I do not know the requirements for all the projects at the moment, but I don't want to rewrite it in a years time when I've forgotten the various methods and algorithms I am using. Read my edits on the questions for clarification.

Comment: @R.., Yes, as long as you are ok retrofitting features. Or you could just do it right the first time, and never look at the code ever again.

Comment: I'm dead scared of code that's never looked at again. Look at the gnulib code in gnu m4 for an atrocious example... It hasn't been touched in 15+ years and it's full of hacks that poke at the internals of every known system's `FILE` structure...

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question, I think we need to know more about what the functions in question do. As a general rule, I would provide at most one floating-point and one integer version unless it's really performance-critical to get the benefit of working on smaller types. `int` is a really bad choice though. I'd use `long`, `long long`, `intmax_t`, or `uintmax_t` depending on whether you want to support C89, your conventions about use of types in the project, and signedness requirements. Or, you could make your own type `mylib_intarg` that lets you change what underlying type is used, but **please** for the sake of sanity **do not** encourage users of your library to declare variables with these ugly types. Instead just make them the argument type for the function so that the caller uses whatever variable types are natural.

Answer (score 1):

Implement it as C++ function templates and add a C wrapper, so that when you need to support say `long long` or `long double` you just add another C wrapper, your C++ algo templates stay intact and you don't need to remember the details.